# More than one user not getting email alerts (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, email, tasks

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010, and I'm creating an application which assigns tasks to other people.

In the application, whenever a person is assigned a task, that particular person (or group of people) who has (have) been assigned that task, will get an email notification about it.

My problem is that I'm the only one who gets an email. No one else gets an email. All of the addresses are correct, and all of our emails are in the same list. What could be the problem?

Additional info which could help: I'm running the workflow which sends out the email through a document library. The document library's list has columns which are a lookup to a "People" list. For each step within the workflow, I tried every possible "Return field as:"

Comment: have you check timer job log called Immediate alert. It might possible the Immediate alert is hung.

Answer (score 2):

couple of things to check.

- Permission of Users on that list/library
- create some test alerts on that list check if it is working.
- Email addresses are on network or off network i.e gmail
- Check if Timer job for email alerts working?

check this guide for detailed troubleshooting steps:

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx